# Carrying a Submitted Name Variable across multiple php pages?

Tags: php, html

On my first page: page1.php I have an input where you type your desired name which I then want to be carried over to more than one page, so far I can get it to page2.php but on page3.php the code fails here is my code

page1.php:

```
       <form action="page2.php" method="post">
Name:  <input type="text" name="username" />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

\

page2.php: (after 5 seconds the page redirects to page3.php)

```
<?php
echo $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
?>
<form action="page3.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="username" />
```

page3.php:

```
<?php
echo $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
?>
```

These lines work on page2.php but not here which is what I can't seem to fix

Comment: format properly please

Comment: I'm not clear why there are paragraph elements all over your code. Please format your code, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks. Are you using `<?php session_start(); ?>` on all pages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between pages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179559/how-do-i-pass-data-between-pages-in-php)

Comment: I suggested an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving you a fish, I'll teach you to fish:

`echo $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];`

This statement is echoing the value ASSIGNED to `$_SESSION['username']`

```
  =  Assignment
 ==  Comparison
===  Comparison (Identical)
```

Answer (score 0):

On page3.php is not working because you pass no value. So:

Instead of:

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" />
```

Go with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="".$_SESSION['username']."">
```

Or:

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="".$_POST['username']."">
```

Now it passes the value and you should get the value on page3.php. One warning is that users can edit your value with DEV tools so I suggest to pass values differently.