# How to bring data to another page in php

Tags: php, oop

As the question, I can do that with `$_SESSION` on the below code, but I would like to do that without using `$_SESSION`, any suggestion ?
I am new for using oop in php.

PHP (page 1):

```
    include './class.php';
    include './next.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
         $data = new myData();
         $data->setTest($_POST['test']);
    }

    $content = '<form method="post" action="next.php">
      <input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="test"/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>';

   if(!empty($next)){
       $content = $next;
   }

   echo $content;
```

class.php:

```
class myData{
     function __construct($test){
          ***some process***
          $_SESSION["test"] = $test;
     }
}
```

next.php

```
$next = $_SESSION["test"];
```

Comment: There are a lot of answers available on this for this issue already - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179559/how-do-i-pass-data-between-pages-in-php. Keep in mind php is stateless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between pages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179559/how-do-i-pass-data-between-pages-in-php)

Comment: The site's solution is using ```$_GET``` on the second page, but I need to pass many data not only a single data as my question.

Comment: [`$_COOKIE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

Comment: ```$_COOKIE``` is not secure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the variable in the class and then use a getter method to get that data back.
file1.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $data = new MyData($_POST['test']);
}


class MyData{
     private $data = '';

     function __construct($test){
          ***some process***
          $data = $test;
     }
     function getData() {
         return $this->data;
     }
}
```

file2.php

```
    include file1.php;
    echo $data->getData();
```

Comment: This no work for me, but I use another way to do it. Thanks you for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

I declare a function and return back to page 1 on `next.php`

```
function showContent($content){
      if(!empty($content)){
            return $content;
      }
      return false;
}
```

Then on the `class.php`, I declare a getter as Mr.[Karim Aljandali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9297128/karim-aljandali)'s answer.
On the page 1 I add a line `$next = showContent($data->getData());`