# Unable to send data from one file to another file

Tags: php, mysql

i have created a php page in which i want that whenever i refresh the page it should shuffle and in that data i want that whenever i click on data it should redirect to a new page where that data should be displayed for this I have used Session to store it.

***home.php***

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","writersplanet");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY RAND()";
$execute = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($execute)) {

    $_SESSION['uploadcoverimg'] = $row['uploadcoverimg'];
    $_SESSION['bookname'] =$row['bookname'];
    $_SESSION['uname'] =$row['uname'];
    $_SESSION['summary'] =$row['summary'];
    $_SESSION['thoughts'] =$row['thoughts'];
    $_SESSION['pdf'] = $row['pdf'];
    $_SESSION['date'] = $row['date'];
    echo "<div class='container' align='center'>
        <a href='readbook.php'>
        <div class='box'>
                <div class='imgbox'>
                    <img src='upload/".$row['uploadcoverimg']."'>
                </div>
                <div class='content'>
                    <h3>".$row['bookname']." <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-right'></i>".$row['uname']."</h3>
                    <p>".$row['summary']."</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        </a>
        <div class='outcome'>
            <div class='heart'>
                <i class='fas fa-heart'></i>
            </div>
            <div class='eye'>
                <i class='fas fa-eye'></i>
            </div>
             <div class='ratings'>
                <i class='fas fa-star-half-alt'></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='scrollmenu1'>
            <a href='#home' style='border-radius: 10px;margin-top: 10px; background-color: black;color: white; width: 65px;height: 30px;box-sizing: border-box;'>Horror</a>
            <a href='#news' style='border-radius: 10px;margin-top: 10px; width: 65px;height: 30px;box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #0a3da3;color: white;'>Sci-Fi</a>
            <a href='#contact' style='border-radius: 10px;margin-top: 10px; background-color: #ff69b4;color: white; width: 65px;height: 30px;box-sizing: border-box;'>Love</a>
        </div>
        <div class='content1'>
                <h2>Time</h2>
                <p><br>
                    Writers Thoughts about this book:
                    ".$row['thoughts']."
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>";
}
?>
```

In my sql code I have used [id, uname, bookname, summary,thoughts,uploadcoverimg,pdf,date].

***readbook.php***

```
<img class='bookcover' src='Desert.jpg'>

        <div class='heading'>
            <h3><?php echo $_SESSION['bookname']; ?> <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-right'></i><?php echo $_SESSION['uname'];?></h3>
        </div>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class="half_star">
            <i id='half_star' class='fas fa-star-half-alt'></i>
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
            <i id='comment' class='fas fa-comments'></i>
        </div>
        <div class="like">
            <i id='like' class='fas fa-thumbs-up'></i><br>
        </div>

        <div class="date">
            <i id='date' class='fas fa-calendar-alt'></i><br>
        <?php echo  $_SESSION['date'];?>
        </div>
        <div class="share">
            <i id='share' class='fas fa-share'></i>
        </div>


        <div class='scrollmenu1'>
            <a class='horror' href='#home' color='white'>Horror</a>
            <a class='sci-fi' href='#news'>Sci-Fi</a>
            <a class='love' href='#contact'>Love</a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class='summary'>
        <h1>Summary of the Book</h1>
        <p><?php echo $_SESSION['summary'];?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="thoughts2">
        <h2 class="quotes_head">Thoughts of the Writer</h2>
        <p><?php echo $_SESSION['thoughts'];?></p>
    </div>

    <div class="storyhead">
        <h1>Let's start the story:</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="taskbar">
        <button class="bookmark"><i id="bookmark" class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>Bookmark</button>
        <button class="unlock"><i id="unlock" class="fas fa-unlock"></i>Unlock</button>
        <button class="download">Download</button>
    </div>



    <div class="pages">
        <a href="upload/<?php echo $_SESSION['pdf'];?>">click here!</a>
        <iframe src="upload/<?php echo $_SESSION['pdf'];?>" width="1000px" height="500px"></iframe>
    </div>
```

If anybody can help me then its a great thank you from my side because this is related to my career planning.
Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass data between pages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179559/how-do-i-pass-data-between-pages-in-php)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply because I am new user in Stackoverflow. The answer is NO..

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

instead of this:

```
   $_SESSION['uploadcoverimg'] = $row['uploadcoverimg'];
    $_SESSION['bookname'] =$row['bookname'];
    $_SESSION['uname'] =$row['uname'];
    $_SESSION['summary'] =$row['summary'];
    $_SESSION['thoughts'] =$row['thoughts'];
    $_SESSION['pdf'] = $row['pdf'];
    $_SESSION['date'] = $row['date'];
```

use this:

```
$query_string = http_build_query($row);
```

change a href url so you append '?$query_string' to the URL

```
        <a href='readbook.php?<?php echo $query_string?>'>
```

and in your readbook.php use $_GET[] instead of $_SESSION[];

There are some limitation on how long a query string can be,  but in your case, I think you have small enough dataset to pass.

Your solution done properly would be using a MySQL connection in the readbook.php while you would pass only a book id from the previous page so that you can select info for the exact book from the database using a query with where clause (i.e. select * from  books where book_id = x).